# Javascript - Disable spaces on all pages except 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to prevent the space button from being pressed on all of my pages except 2 where I have textareas. I need spaces on these textarea pages so the user can enter in their support ticket message. I have tried many different ways of doing this and cannot find a working way. I've spent about 1 whole week just trying this small error. I thought it was time to get some help.

The error is that when I use the code below, it tells me that I cannot use spaces (and prevents spaces) eventhough I am on one of the pages I said not to run the script on.

*My current code is :*

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {

var myUrl_one = '/panel/staff?page=tickets';
var myUrl_two = '/panel/support';

var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;

if(currentUrl != myUrl_one || currentUrl != myUrl_two) {
        if (event.which == 32) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.Notification.autoHideNotify('error', 'top right', 'Keyboard Error!', 'No spaces are allowed here!');
        }
}

});
```

Comment: I think you need to replace the `||` with `&&` in your `if` condition.

Comment: @Airwavezx Okay, I have but now it's only working on my myUrl_two url, not my myUrl_one.

Comment: try debugging it. use `console.log(currentUrl, myUrl_one)` and see if they are actually equal. My best guess is that they aren't and you have a minor error in your code.

Comment: @Airwavezx Thank you very much! I will add a answer below with my fixed code.

Comment: my pleasure :) upvote the people who help you out (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @RogerCageot and @Airwavezx, I have found the issue.

Firstly, I needed to change my || operator to && in my if statement like so :

```
if(currentUrl != myUrl_one && currentUrl != myUrl_two) {
```

Secondly, the javascript function window.location.pathname only gets the raw path location, not `GET` parameters. Because I was trying to get `/panel/staff?page=tickets`, it wasn't reading the `?page=tickets`. It was only reading the `/panel/staff`.

My fully working code is below :

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {

var myUrl_one = '/panel/staff';
var myUrl_two = '/panel/support';

var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;

if(currentUrl != myUrl_one && currentUrl != myUrl_two) {
    if (event.which == 32) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.Notification.autoHideNotify('error', 'top right', 'Keyboard Error!', 'No spaces are allowed here!');
        console.log(currentUrl, myUrl_one);
    }
}

});
```